# Comparing two columns using SQL to make sure the same set of values are present in both

Tags: sql

I have following columns to compare. Need to make sure that all values in code column in table 1 is present in code column in table 2. Both have codes stored in different order. Need to loop and check each row value against each row value in other table.

table 1

```
Id  Code
1    2 
1    3
1    1 
1    4
```

Table 2

```
Id Code
1   1
1   2
1   3
1   4
```

Comment: What if the ids are different?

Comment: What results do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Minus function will give you the difference between two statements:

```
select id, code
from table_1
minus
select id, code
from table_2
```

Comment: This would be 'EXCEPT' in SQL Server. RDBMS needs to be tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Simply  join the two

```
Select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2
On t1.id=t2.id and t1.code=t2.code
```

Or use exists/In

```
  Select * from table1 t1 
  where exists(
  Select 1 from table2 t2 where 
   t1.id=t2.id and t1.code=t2.code)


    Select * from table1 t1
    where id, code
   In (
   Select id, code from table2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` to get the missing codes:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from table2 t2
                  where t2.id = t1.id and t2.code = t1.code
                 );
```